# Cross Compiling wxWidgets under Linux to WIndows using MinGW

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, cross-compiling, wxwidgets

I would like to cross compile the Hello World tutorial for Windows. I've followed the instructions on wxWidgets wiki : downloaded the source files, compiled it using

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-linux && make && sudo make install
```

I use CLion IDE and it use CMake, so I changed my CMakeList;Txt to :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(wxWidgets)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS net core base)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
if(WIN32)
    set(SRCS ${SRCS} minimal.rc)
endif(WIN32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)
add_executable(wxWidgets WIN32 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(wxWidgets ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

I got some errors compiling it (Missing headers file I think)
I not very friendly with CMake and particularly with importing and linking externals libraries....

Here you can see the errors :

```
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/defs.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxprec.h:12,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Dev/C++/wxWidgets/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/platform.h:438:13: fatal error: wx/msw/libraries.h: No such file or folder
  438 | #   include "wx/msw/libraries.h"
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/wxWidgets.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/wxWidgets.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/wxWidgets.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/wxWidgets.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: wxWidgets] Error 2
```

I would like to notice that I have a Windows computer too and I could easily jump into windows and compile it here. But this is not my goal I really want to understand how the process of linking and cross-compiling works.

**EDIT :**

After updating my CMakeList it looks like all the files are found but now I got a lot of errors of undefined things :

**CMakeList :**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(wxWidgets)

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS net core base)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH )
if(WIN32)
    set(SRCS ${SRCS} minimal.rc)
endif(WIN32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)
add_executable(wxWidgets WIN32 main.cpp)
target_include_directories(wxWidgets PRIVATE /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1)
target_link_libraries(wxWidgets ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

**Errors :**

```
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/platform.h:529,
                 from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/wxprec.h:12,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Dev/C++/wxWidgets/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/chkconf.h:282:9: error: #error "wxUSE_SECRETSTORE must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
  282 | #       error "wxUSE_SECRETSTORE must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
      |         ^~~~~
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/chkconf.h:322:9: error: #error "wxUSE_STD_CONTAINERS_COMPATIBLY must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
  322 | #       error "wxUSE_STD_CONTAINERS_COMPATIBLY must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
      |         ^~~~~
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/chkconf.h:378:9: error: #error "wxUSE_UNSAFE_WXSTRING_CONV must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
  378 | #       error "wxUSE_UNSAFE_WXSTRING_CONV must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
      |         ^~~~~
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/chkconf.h:446:9: error: #error "wxUSE_ADDREMOVECTRL must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
  446 | #       error "wxUSE_ADDREMOVECTRL must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
      |         ^~~~~
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/chkconf.h:454:9: error: #error "wxUSE_ACTIVITYINDICATOR must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
  454 | #       error "wxUSE_ACTIVITYINDICATOR must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
      |         ^~~~~
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/chkconf.h:988:9: error: #error "wxUSE_PRIVATE_FONTS must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
  988 | #       error "wxUSE_PRIVATE_FONTS must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
      |         ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/chkconf.h:1268,
                 from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/platform.h:529,
                 from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/wxprec.h:12,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Dev/C++/wxWidgets/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/msw/chkconf.h:27:10: error: #error "wxUSE_WINRT must be defined."
   27 | #        error "wxUSE_WINRT must be defined."
      |          ^~~~~
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/msw/chkconf.h:43:9: error: #error "wxUSE_DBGHELP must be defined"
   43 | #       error "wxUSE_DBGHELP must be defined"
      |         ^~~~~
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/msw/chkconf.h:107:9: error: #error "wxUSE_TASKBARBUTTON must be defined."
  107 | #       error "wxUSE_TASKBARBUTTON must be defined."
      |         ^~~~~
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/msw/chkconf.h:123:10: error: #error "wxUSE_WINSOCK2 must be defined."
  123 | #        error "wxUSE_WINSOCK2 must be defined."
      |          ^~~~~
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/msw/chkconf.h:386:13: error: #error "wxUSE_DRAG_AND_DROP requires wxUSE_OLE"
  386 | #           error "wxUSE_DRAG_AND_DROP requires wxUSE_OLE"
      |             ^~~~~
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/msw/chkconf.h:397:13: error: #error "wxMediaCtl requires wxActiveXContainer"
  397 | #           error "wxMediaCtl requires wxActiveXContainer"
      |             ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/platform.h:529,
                 from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/wxprec.h:12,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Dev/C++/wxWidgets/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/chkconf.h:1305:13: error: #error "2.8.X compatibility requires 3.0.X compatibility"
 1305 | #           error "2.8.X compatibility requires 3.0.X compatibility"
      |             ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/wxprec.h:12,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Dev/C++/wxWidgets/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h: In function ‘wxUIntPtr wxPtrToUInt(const void*)’:
/usr/include/wx-3.0_win/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:906:41: error: cast from ‘const void*’ to ‘wxUIntPtr’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} loses precision [-fpermissive]
  906 |     return reinterpret_cast<wxUIntPtr>(p);
      |                                         ^
```

Comment: Looks like missing include paths to me. Try to add `target_include_directories(wxWidgets PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})` to your CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Hi @vre thanks for helping.
I've added this line : `target_include_directories(wxWidgets PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})`
Unfortunately I get the same errors.

Comment: Is that a typo? The variable to use for the `target_include_directories` command is `wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS` not `wxWidgets_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: @vre Sorry for that, I'm really not friendly with CMake & externals libraries...

I changed
 `target_include_directories(wxWidgets PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})`

to : 
`target_include_directories(wxWidgets PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

Also tried :
 `target_include_directories(wxWidgets PRIVATE wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)`

Always the same errors...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the *contents* of `${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}`? Can you add `message("${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}")` to the end of your CMake file?

Comment: Hi @squareskittles lot of thanks for helping.
I added `message("${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}")` at the end of my CMakeList but didn't get any output about it.
I only get the same errors as above.

Comment: This variable *should* be populated after the CMake call `find_package(wxWidgets ...)`. If it is not populated, I would think CMake fails because you have the `REQUIRED` keyword. Can you provide the *full* CMake output log?

Comment: @squareskittles Sorry for double tag and double comment but I just missed the ouput sorry... so it's `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0;/usr/include/wx-3.0`
It's pretty bad because my compiled version of wxWidget with mingw is located at `/usr/include/wx-3.0_win

Comment: If you have a bunch of different wxwidget versions on your machine, you have to tell `find_package()` *which* one to use. Consider reading the [search procedure](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure) documentation for `find_package()`.